# Como filtrar registros por mês no Python / Flask

Tags: python, flask, orm, sqlalchemy

Olá, pessoal. Tudo bom?

Comecei a aprender programação há um tempo e aproveitei essa quarentena para dar um gás e conseguir criar meu primeiro sistema - um gerenciador de vales/adiantamentos.
É simples, a pessoa solicita um vale com um determinado valor e depois, no dashboard, todos os vales solicitados por essa pessoa e o valor do salário dela atualizado aparece.

Acontece que agora eu estou tentando fazer uma melhoria que não sei por onde começar. Eu quero que a pessoa selecione um mês do ano e todos os vales solicitados nesse mês selecionado apareçam.

Eu sei que é uma dúvida simples, mas matutei aqui de todo jeito e não cheguei numa resposta. Se puderem me ajudar eu agradeço muito!

Para constar, estou usando o python e o flask com blueprints e sqlalchemy.

Com o que já tenho agora eu consigo exibir todos os vales solicitados pelo usuário dessa forma na view:

```
@core.route('/dashboard')
@login_required
def dashboard():
    vales = Withdrawals.query.filter_by(solicitante = current_user)
    total_vales = 0
    total_qt_vales = 0

    for vale in vales:
        total_vales = total_vales + vale.value
        total_qt_vales = total_qt_vales + 1

    salario_total = current_user.salary - total_vales




    return render_template('dashboard.html', vales=vales, salario_total=salario_total, total_qt_vales=total_qt_vales)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então, queria um pouco mais de informação pra tentar te ajudar, mas pelo que você forneceu vou te apresentar uma alternativa:

Os vales que você mencionou estão salvos no seu database ne? Se sim, então você tem uma classe que representa esse modelo e suas colunas de atributos, dessa forma você poderia adicionar, por exemplo:

```
class Vale(db.Model):
   #... colunas
   mes = db.Column(#Aqui você pode receber como uma data(db.DateTime) ou de outra foma)
```

Sendo assim, sempre que o usuário entrar com um mês, você faz uma procura no banco de dados:

```
exemplo = Vale.query.filter_by(mes=mes).all()
```

Se você quiser apenas os vales de um determinado mês de um usuário específico (**user logado**), então provavelmente o modelo do user deve ter uma coluna com uma lista de vales, e esses vales, como mencionei acima, terá o seu mês em que foi solicitado registrado no seu banco, então basta acessá-los e filtra-los pelo user.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Sei que podem ter faltado vários detalhes, mas sua resposta me deu uma ótima ideia que acho que vai funcionar.

Comment: Sem problema irmao, qualquer coisa so falar, se puder dar um up na resposta tambem , abraços

Comment: Opa! Já dei o up aqui mas como minha rep é baixa não aparece :/ kk